# Kafka Consumer to ingest data without querying DB for every message

Tags: database, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

We have a Kafka consumer service to ingest data into our DB. Whenever we receive the message from the topic we will compose an insert statement to insert this message into DB. We use DB connection pool to handle the insertion and so far so good.

Currently, we need to add a filter to select only the related message from Kafka and do the insert. There are two options in my mind to do this.

### Option 1:  Create a config table in the DB to define our filtering condition.

**Pros**

1. No need to make code changes or redeploy services
2. Just insert new filters to config table, service will pick them the next run

**Cons**

1. eed to query the DB every time we receive new messages.
2. Say we received 100k new messages daily and need to filter out 50k. So totally we only need to run `50k INSERT` commands, while need to run `100K SELECT queries` to check the filter condition `for every single Kafka message`.

### Option 2: Use a hardcoded config file to define those filters.

**Pros**

1. Only need to read the filters once when the consumer start running
2. Has no burden on the DB layer

**Cons**

1. This is not a scalable way since we are planning to add a lot of filters, everytime we need to make code changes on the config file and redeploy the consumer.

My question is, is there a better option to achieve the goal? Find the filters without using hardcoded config file or without increasing the concurrency of DB queries.

Comment: Why cant you mix both, instead of keeping it in config file, keep it in DB, read it once on startup and use it to filter. May be a cache OR a singleton object to hold value.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Can you elaborate what a cache option will be like?

Comment: If you're using Java, look at Guava or Caffeine cache libraries

Answer (score 1):

Your filters could be in another Kafka topic.

Start your app and read the topic until the end, and only then start doing database inserts. Store each consumed record in some local structure such as ConcurrentHashmap, SQLite, RocksDB (provided by Kafka Streams), or DuckDB is popular recently...

When you add a new filter, your consumer would need to temporarily pause your database operations

If you use Kafka Streams, then you could lookup data from the incoming topic against your filters "table" statestore using Processor API and drop the records from the stream

This way, you separate your database reads and writes once you start inserting 50k+ records, and your app wouldn't be blocked trying to read any "external config"

You could also use Zookeeper, as that's one of its use cases